# C# No ejecuta procedimiento almacenado + trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, stored-procedure, trigger

Amigos como estan!!

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que Inserta registros en una tabla, el cual ejecuto desde una aplicación WinForms, estuve haciendo unas modificaciones y le añadi un Trigger a la tabla a la cual el procedimiento inserta los datos.

Pero ya el procedimiento ejecutado desde WinForms no es capaz de insertar los datos si la tabla tiene el trigger, pero si le quito el trigger a la tabla este procedimiento vuelve a funcionar.

Trigger:

```sql
USE [BD_SICAP_AG_PRUEBAS]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TR_AGREGAR_DETALLE_SEGUIMIENTO]    Script Date: 14/06/2018 09:06:47 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_AGREGAR_DETALLE_SEGUIMIENTO]
ON [dbo].[TDETALLE_PROGRAMACION] FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE
@IdProgramacion int,
@FechaProgramacion date,
@NombreRuta varchar (150),
@PlacaVehiculo varchar (6),
@NombreConductor varchar (50),
@HoraSalida varchar (5),
@DiaAnterior char (1),
@HoraLlegadaProveedor varchar (5),
@Observaciones varchar (150)
SELECT @IdProgramacion=IdProgramacion, @FechaProgramacion = FechaProgramacion, 
@NombreRuta=NombreRuta,
@PlacaVehiculo=PlacaVehiculo,
@NombreConductor=NombreConductor,
@HoraSalida=HoraSalida,
@DiaAnterior=DiaAnterior,
@HoraLlegadaProveedor=HoraLlegadaProveedor,
@Observaciones=Observaciones FROM inserted
INSERT INTO TSEGUIMIENTO VALUES (@IdProgramacion, @FechaProgramacion, @NombreRuta, @PlacaVehiculo, 
@NombreConductor, @HoraSalida, @DiaAnterior,'','',@HoraLlegadaProveedor,'','','','','','','','','', @Observaciones,'')
```

¿Me pueden brindar una guia de porque puede suceder esto?

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Será un problema con el trigger probablemente.Si quieres mas ayuda, tendrás que dar mas información,por ejemplo el codigo del trigger

Comment: probaste el trigger? pareceria andar mal

Comment: El trigger funciona lo probe desde el management de sql e inserta datos correctamente.

Comment: Y probaste hacer algo que altere la tabla para que ejecute el update? asi en el aire es muy dificil ayudarte

Comment: Si, desde el management ejecute un insert y efectivamente el trigger se dispara y realiza su función. pero desde visual studio cuando compilo la aplicación y ejecuto la tarea no se ejecuta, voy a editar la pregunta para compartir el trigger

Comment: por favor postea el código del trigger. Quizás tus pruebas de funcionamiento del mismo están incorrectas (por ejemplo pruebas insertando sólo una fila a la vez y el trigger funciona, pero desde C# insertas varias filas y se cae)

Comment: Desde c# probe ejecutando una fila y luego varias filas e igual no se ejecuta

Comment: Y que error tira desde codigo?

Comment: Bueno, el código de tu trigger muestra claramente un problema, asume que cada vez se modifica una fila, y no está pensado para operaciones que afecten más de una fila a la vez. En tu caso, no hace ningún sentido que primero guardes los valores en una variable y luego insertes esos valores. Deberías simplemente hacer el insert directo a tu tabla desde la seudo tabla `INSERTED`

Comment: Me puedes regalar un ejemplo pequeño de como lo puedo mejorar?

Comment: ok, postearé una respuesta preliminar (porque si bien tienes un problema, no sé si sea la solución a tu pregunta principal)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Igual este trigger deberia estar tirando un error en el codigo, y estaria bien que el mismo estuviera en la pregutna

Comment: @gbianchi la verdad es que no tiene por qué tirar error, simplemente no hace lo que se espera que haga

Comment: En ese caso, deberia ser mas explicita la pregunta.. con resultado esperado y resultado obtenido.. ya esta, pero es como para tener en cuenta...

Comment: @gbianchi por eso puse en un comentario que es una respuesta preliminar, porque soluciona un problema, pero no necesariamente el problema de la pregunta del op

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualmente el código de tu trigger asume que cada vez se modifican (o insertan) solo una fila de datos, no está preparado para momentos en que se modifiquen más de uno.

De la forma que estás usando el trigger, la solución es muy simple, saltarte el primer paso donde guardas los valores en una variable e insertar directamente desde la seudo tabla `INSERTED`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_AGREGAR_DETALLE_SEGUIMIENTO]
ON [dbo].[TDETALLE_PROGRAMACION] FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO TSEGUIMIENTO 
SELECT  IdProgramacion, FechaProgramacion, NombreRuta, PlacaVehiculo, 
        NombreConductor,HoraSalida,DiaAnterior,'','',
        HoraLlegadaProveedor,'','','','','','','','','',Observaciones,'' 
FROM INSERTED
;
```